# Find all rented cards using EXCEPT or NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql

My Database is like this

```
CUSTOMER (NAME,VAT,PHONE)
CAR(PLATENR,COLOUR)
RENTS(VAT,PLATENR, RENTDATE)
```

What I want to find is all the black cars that were rented by all customers (all VAT Numbers).
I want to use nested subqueries and `EXCEPT` or `NOT EXISTS`. 
I already have this query using `COUNT` that works.

```
SELECT rents.PlateNr
FROM Rents,Car
WHERE Car.colour='black' AND car.PlateNr=rents.PlateNr
GROUP BY rents.PlateNr
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT VAT) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customer);
```

I am trying to use this guide http://www.inf.usi.ch/faculty/soule/teaching/2016-fall/db/division.pdf to get my result but I don't get how the query is implemented in my case.

Comment: for our understanding, why do you specifically want to use EXCEPT or NOT EXISTS while you already have a working query ?

Comment: I am just curious of how this works. The way with count is pretty clear. The other way is a little confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking an answer similar to the link that I provided above regarding division.

After some search and try the final division query using except is this:

```
SELECT PlateNr
FROM Car
WHERE colour='black' 
EXCEPT
    SELECT PlateNr
    FROM (SELECT car.PlateNr, rents.VAT
        FROM car,rents
        EXCEPT
            SELECT PlateNr,VAT
            FROM rents)
```

Have tried it in POSTGRE that supports EXCEPT and everything works like a charm.